# Ffmpeg inaccurate cutting with ts and m3u8 files despite resamping audio filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to accurately seek and cut a video. Some online sources say put -ss in front or after the source. The result is the same for me. In the examples below, the start time is accurate but the duration is not accurate.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:05 -i output.ts 5s.wav
ffprobe 5s.wav

Duration: 00:00:04.74

ffmpeg -y -i output.ts -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:05 5s.wav
ffprobe 5s.wav

Duration: 00:00:04.74
```

Sometimes the starting point is not accurate but the duration is. This is clearly audible by cutting the ts file and cutting an uncompressed wav file, and listening to both.

```
ffmpeg -y -i output.ts -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:05 5s.wav

ffmpeg -y -i output.wav -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:05 5s-reference.wav
```

What fixes the starting time is if I use an m3u8 file that contains the byte offset for every keyframe AND I put the -ss option in front of the source file (if I put it after the source, the start time is inaccurate but the duration is accurate):

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:05 -i output.m3u8 5s.wav
```

This fixes the start time but the duration is at the location that I would get had I used no m3u8 file (duration is just 4.47s).

It seems different timestamps are involved, and sometimes one or the other gets used.

The ts file was generated by capturing a UDP stream and storing it with ffmpeg and -codec:v copy.

Is ffmpeg broken, or the ts file? How do I work around this issue or fix the ts file? What I realize is that the video starts later than the audio, probably because the video does not start with a keyframe. Can I get ffmpeg to start the -codec:v copy after the first keyframe? What I also notice is that using ffprobe reports "start: 1.400000". Can I force it to start at 0?

Any hints would be appreciated.

I tried both ffmpeg 4.3.1 and ffmpeg git-2020-07-24-21442a8.

The output.* files were generated as follows. The statement "af aresample=async=1" should fill missing audio according to [Duration of source video and subtracted audio are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136242/duration-of-source-video-and-subtracted-audio-are-different). Adding this statement makes no difference in terms of accuracy or duration. The question is not a duplicate.

```
ffmpeg -i udp://example:port ^
-af aresample=async=1 ^
-codec:v copy ^
-codec:a aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -b:a 160k ^
-hls_time 4 -hls_flags single_file -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename output.ts -hls_segment_type mpegts output.m3u8 ^
-codec:a pcm_s16le -bitexact -ar 11025 -ac 1 output.wav
```

Comment: The aresample here does not apply to the wav output.

Comment: To what does it apply if not to the output? If it applies to just the HLS output but not the WAV output this still doesn't explain why the duration is not accurate. The inaccurate duration occurs when trying to cut the HLS file, not the WAV file.

Comment: Your last command generates HLS, doesn't cut it and contains both video and audio - so it needs to be diagnosed separately. Your original Q, which appears to be now deleted, only generated audio and resampling takes care of duration in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HLS as input, use

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:13 -copyts -start_at_zero -i input.m3u8 -af aresample=async=1 -ss 15 -to 20 -map 0:a ts-cut-m3u8.wav
```

Seek a bit earlier than the actual inpoint since TS segments have no global index and hence demuxer seek will start from the next keyframe. Since timestamps are being copied, use output ss/to to set range. aresample will plug timestamp gaps if any. For this input, in the 15 to 20 range there aren't any. There's one earlier at around the 5s mark.

Comment: I am deeply impressed. It works perfectly. Thank you very much! I have removed the proprietary http:// links in my original question, as the files have been removed from the web server. If you remove the link in your answer, it will be perfect and serve well for everyone in the future without producing 404. Thanks again!