# ffplay inaccurate cutting with ts and m3u8 files

Tags: ffmpeg

Ffmpeg is able to cut media files accurately according to the following article:
[Ffmpeg inaccurate cutting with ts and m3u8 files despite resamping audio filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188134/ffmpeg-inaccurate-cutting-with-ts-and-m3u8-files-despite-resamping-audio-filter)

It uses the flags `-copyts -start_at_zero` with ffmpeg. These flags are not available for ffplay. Is it possible to reach frame-accurate seeking for playback?

If not: Is it possible to pre-process the file (e.g. embed the effects of `-copyts -start_at_zero` into the ts file) so that those flags are no longer needed? (Simply re-encoding the video with `-copyts -start_at_zero` does not yield the right results)

*Expected*

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:13 -copyts -start_at_zero -i http://tyberis.com/output.m3u8 -af aresample=async=1 -ss 15 -to 20 -map 0:a ts-cut-m3u8.wav
ffplay ts-cut-m3u8.wav
```

*Actual*

```
ffplay http://tyberis.com/output.m3u8 -af aresample=async=1 -ss 15
```

The inaccuracy is around 0.3s in this small example file (the inaccuracy is larger in other files).

Comment: If you don't care about seeking after starting playback simply pipe ffmpeg output to ffplay

Comment: I need to avoid re-encoding during playback. The m3u8 already contains re-encoded audio from the other stackoverflow question. I would prefer "sanitizing" the stream upfront, so that I can operate on the m3u8 in a trouble-free way later on.