# Ffmpeg seeking with m3u8 ineffective

Tags: ffmpeg

Following the answer at [Ffmpeg inaccurate cutting with ts and m3u8 files despite resamping audio filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188134/ffmpeg-inaccurate-cutting-with-ts-and-m3u8-files-despite-resamping-audio-filter), I am cutting some portion out of an m3u8 file.

My m3u8 has a segment every 4 seconds, so I seek to a location around 10 seconds before the cutting point with -ss before -i. Then adjust position with -ss after -i.

Here are two examples where the starting cut points are off by 1s:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 0:03:22 -start_at_zero -i http://tyberis.com/CFTE-AM_2020-08-28_23-00-00.m3u8 -ss 1 -t 0:00:10 322.wav
```

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 0:03:23 -start_at_zero -i http://tyberis.com/CFTE-AM_2020-08-28_23-00-00.m3u8 -ss 1 -t 0:00:10 323.wav
```

When I compare the two output files, they are binary same:

```
diff 323.wav 322.wav -s
Files 323.wav and 322.wav are identical
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I accurately seek to the desired position?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the start position twice, you should set the start position before the input to make Ffmpeg start reading the input from there.
Setting the seeking flag after the input makes it process the whole input.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 0:03:23 -i http://tyberis.com/CFTE-AM_2020-08-28_23-00-00.m3u8 -t 0:00:10 323.wav
```

Comment: Setting it twice is how it's done according to the documentation and according to the answer linked above, answer was by ffmpeg maintainer.

Comment: @LemonSky Yes but you ask it first to start reading from the 3m23s mark and then ask it to start encoding from the first second, it's conflicting.

Comment: Where's the conflict? Your approach will read the entire file from the beginning, it will work of course, but I am dealing with files 9 GB. The purpose of the single-file m3u8 is to be able to jump to an approximate location fast, then slow seek accurately from there. Ffmpeg documentation refers to this as "combined seeking", it generally works fine, just not in the specific example posted above.

Comment: @LemonSky You are totally right. I changed my answer, i copied the wrong line from my terminal.

Comment: If I execute your example, once with 0:03:23 and once with 0:03:22, the two outputs are identical, therefore, seeking can't be accurate.

Comment: My solution now is to parse m3u8 programmatically myself, look for the nearest cut point, extract the byte range to create a new ts file, then use slow-seeking (after -ss -i) to cut the file, i.e. ffmpeg does not deal with the m3u8 file. In that case, it works, which is why I guess this is either a limitation or a bug (or wrong usage on my end)